# Capturing Dockerfile variable in file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

in a Dockerfile I'm trying to capture a build arg variable inside a file with no luck.

Now I'm doing something such as:

```
RUN echo '\n\
enableSemantics( "$DOMAIN_NAME" );\n\
include_once "$IP/LocalSettings.local.php"; ' >> /var/www/w/LocalSettings.php
```

and I would like to replace $DOMAIN_NAME with DOMAIN_NAME build ARG (but not $IP, which is not...)

What should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inverting the quotes :

```
ARG DOMAIN_NAME
RUN echo "\n\
enableSemantics( '$DOMAIN_NAME' );\n\
include_once '$IP/LocalSettings.local.php'; " >> /var/www/w/LocalSettings.php
```

I don't know the exact reason , why this works , but most probably , its how Docker resolves the variables , i.e it ignores variables between double quotes.

Also you can skip the `$` in this way : `\$`

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Actually, for this specific case I had to do a bit more change: RUN echo "\n\
enableSemantics( '${DOMAIN_NAME}' );\n\
include_once \"\$IP/LocalSettings.local.php\"; " >> /var/www/w/LocalSettings.php